# Can this motherboard drive a 4k monitor?

Tags: display, motherboard, integrated-graphics

Can the "[MSI H81M-P33](https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16813130731)" drive [this](https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16824025172?Item=N82E16824025172&nm_mc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel&cm_mmc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel-_-Content-_-text-_-) 4k monitor?

Comment: Probably not but you can add a graphics card that can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSI H81M-P33 has only two graphic ports: One VGA and one DVI port. Neither can drive a 4K monitor.

For a 4K monitor you need a DisplayPort v1.2 or a HDMI 2.0 port for transferring a 4K image with regular refresh speed (60Hz).